# XMLHTTPRequest not receiving response from LotusScript agent

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, lotusscript

I have a LotusScript agent that has the following code at the end

```
Set nam = session.Createname(respParty)
Print "Content-type: text/plain"
Print nam.Abbreviated
```

I have a JavaScript button that contains the following prior to a submit()

```
    var noEmployees = document.getElementById('NoEmployees').value;
    var stateName = document.getElementById('State').value;
    var url = 'http://' + window.location.host + '/ebsprospects.nsf/GetResponsiblePerson?OpenAgent&NoEmployees=' + noEmployees + '&State=' + stateName;     
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", url);

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {           
        }
    };
    alert (xhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById("ResponsibleParty").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
```

Everything is working except it is getting back a blank value.

If I put the URL:

> http://[webaddress]/[dbname].nsf/GetResponsiblePerson?OpenAgent&NoEmployees=20&State=IL

into the browser exactly as I am passing it into the JS code it returns:

```
    X Content-type: text/plain Susanne Anderson/CBS
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is my JS code in the wrong order?

Comment: I think you need to define your onreadystatechange before doing the .open(). Also put your alert  and the innerHTML statements inside the IF statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var noEmployees = document.getElementById('NoEmployees').value;
    var stateName = document.getElementById('State').value;
    var url = 'http://' + window.location.host + '/ebsprospects.nsf/GetResponsiblePerson?OpenAgent&NoEmployees=' + noEmployees + '&State=' + stateName;     
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", url);

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {          
         alert (xhttp.responseText);
         document.getElementById("ResponsibleParty").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.send();
```

Hope this will help.